# What is the fastest way to encapsulate an index offset access for an array?

Tags: java

For modeling quite an amount of calculations, I need to combine speed with some convenience for the writer and reader of the code.

The first important part is to calculate and store data indexed by year of birth, gender, age, etc .

For example I have a year of birth range from 1900 to 2050. Because I cant declare a non zero indexed array from 1950 to 2050, I want to encapsulate the index shift from [0..150] to [1900..2050]. Obviously it is less error prone and easier to read and write code like

```
valueArray.setValue(1950, someValue);
```

than

```
valueArray[1950 - 1900] = someValue;
```

if you have to do it hundreds of times with multiple different array ranges.

Speed is crucial for my task. So I want to know is there a better faster way than the for me obvious one shown below. Are there completly different approaches to solving this problem you would take?

```java
public class OffsetArray {

    private int min;
    private int max;
    private double initValue;
    private double[] values;

    public OffsetArray( int min, int max, double initValue ) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        this.values = new double[max-min+1];
        this.initValue = initValue;
        this.init();
    }

    private void init() {
        for ( int i = 0; i<max-min+1;i++) {
            values[i] = this.initValue;
        }
    }

    public double getValue(int index) {
        return values[index-min];
    }

    public void setValue(int index, double value ) {
        this.values[index-min] = value;
    }

    public int getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    public int getMax() {
        return max;
    }
```

Edited additional requirements:

I need these kind of arrays with multiple dimensions and with ranges starting with negative numbers, i.e. [-50..50].

Comment: This is fine and very efficient. Storing the initValue as a field is unnecessary (and confusing, though.

Comment: You are right. If I store the initValue, I should make the init() method public.

Comment: If you need speed just trash 1950 values and use a `new double[2050]` ignoring the shift. The memory wasted is probably negligible. I wouldn't mind for roughly 16Kb of RAM unless you need thousands of these objects or your ranges are a lot larger.

Comment: You may want to incorporate some exception handling that throws an exception with a customized message to alert you to where the problem lies and the values involved (like if  `index-min is < 0`).

Comment: actually extending the range starting from might be an option I have to test... memory might not be a problem, but I would have to encapsulate  some range checking, which probably costs some speed... and what do I do with ranges starting with negative number, for example [-50..50]?

Comment: For ranges with a -50 to 50 you just create the class with a different offset so you use that range.  Arrays naturally are 0 based.  You would just create one that is -50 based.

Comment: yeah, my proposed class already satisfies the requirement for negative indices. without any changes. Every other solution must also be measured against this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a HashMap?  They are pretty efficient and let you "index" based on a key.

```java
      Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
      map.computeIfAbsent("1900-2000", k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(10);
      map.computeIfAbsent("1900-2000", k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(20);
      map.computeIfAbsent("1900-2000", k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(30);

      System.out.println(map.get("1900-2000"));
```

You could have some method that creates the key based on the state of the value (Object) in question.

Comment: It's not faster. Your solution is only limited by your subtraction in `values[index-min]`, whereas a HashMap computes hashes and when buckets starts to fill, retrieval gets slower. You can see the implementation of HashMap [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java).

Comment: The question is what is fast enough?  Were there performance issues prior to the OP's solution?  Only the OP can't answer that.  And showing the hashMap implementation is not telling the whole story.  You can also fine tune the map to be more efficient than its default settings.  But only the OP can tell for certain.

Comment: at the moment I cant tell what is fast enough. Im starting modeling at the moment and because this class is so crucial for the task I wanted some opinions in advance. In the end faster is always better :)